# VueJS Transition depending on whether a link is behind or before the current link in navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, transition

I am using VueJS to create a SPA and have a Transition for the content when I go to another route (for example via navbar).

At the moment the current content slides to the left and the new content comes in from the right side.

Now I want to detect whether the content should slide in from left or right, depending on: if the position of the link in the navbar is before or behind the current route.

For example, I have a navbar with following items:
**Home**, **References**, **Contact**

When I am on the **References** page and click **Contact**, the content should come in from right. But when I click **Home**, the content should come in from left.

How would you implement that?

Thank you very much in advance! <3

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <Header/> // header will not change

        <transition name="slide">
            <router-view></router-view> // here comes the new content
        </transition>

        <Footer/> // footer will not change
    </div>
</template>
```

```css
.slide-enter-active {
    transition: all .3s ease-out .35s;
}
.slide-leave-active {
    transition: all .2s ease-in;
}
.slide-enter {
    transform: translateX(100%);
}
.slide-leave-to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a metafield with a notion of 'order' to your routes.

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: ...,
      component: ...,
      children: [
        {
          path: 'link1',
          component: linkOne,
          // a meta field
          meta: { order: 1 }
        },
        {
          path: 'link2',
          component: linkTwo,
          // a meta field
          meta: { order: 2 }
        },
        {
          path: 'link3',
          component: linkThree,
          // a meta field
          meta: { order: 3 }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

You'll have to use a variable/method for your transition name:

```
<transition :name="transitionName"></transition>
```

Then, based on the order of the current route and the target route you can determine which transition to apply and store in transitionName variable.
( You can access meta data with `this.$route.meta`)